# JQuery .change() works just once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this piece of javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    const select = $('...'); //it's a simple select
    const input = $('...'); //it's a simple input

    select.change(doSomething());
    input.change(doSomething());

    function doSomething(){

        console.log("yes");

    }

}
```

In console is printed `yes` by twice, when page is loaded.

When I change the value of select or input, the `yes` is no longer printed in console.

`jquery version: 3.4.0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should pass `doSomething` function to the change param. not its execution result.

```
select.change(doSomething);
input.change(doSomething);
```